# How does this site achieve responsive layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Can somebody throw some light as to what are the various ways this Site is using to be responsive. Especially how is the top and left navigation changing to drop down , when you when you re size the browser.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com

I am sure this doesn't use twitter bootstrap. Are they any better ways to go responsive without leveraging twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Responsive design has been around in name longer than Twitter Bootstrap, and in principal it has been around for even longer.

> Are they any better ways to go responsive without leveraging twitter
>   bootstrap.

"Better" is subjective, but there are many ways:

- Another out of the box framework
- [Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)
- JavaScript to adjust the page layout (your own, or something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/))
- Floating elements which wrap based on width
- Percentage-based layouts
- All of the above

The site you linked to actually has good info on responsive design: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/

These frameworks look interesting:

- http://framelessgrid.com/
- http://webexpedition18.com/articles/responsive-css-frameworks/
- http://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: @Mike - added a few links for out of the box frameworks that look promising. I usually write my own layouts, so I don't really have a preference for a particular framework.

Comment: @TimMedora: Exactly thats my question how do you achieve without responsiveness without using framework. what are the principles to acheive this. I heard like using % instead of px and ems for font-size. But I want something in detail.

Comment: @Mike - you could write a book on the subject (and people have) like Ethan Marcotte who made the term popular: http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design/. The series of Smashing Magazine tutorials I linked to in my post would also be a good start. Even if you don't want to use a framework, you can look at their stylesheets as a point of reference.